# How to find a family in a group of individuals

Tags: algorithm, set, grouping, subset

Say I have a group S of potential family members. I define a family as a set of individuals, which contains one or two adults (over 18 years old) and at most 9 children (under 24 years old), but with the condition that every children has to be at least 15 years younger than both of the adults.

An example:

```
id: 1    age: 14
id: 2    age: 25
id: 4    age: 6
id: 5    age: 35
id: 6    age: 50
id: 7    age: 44
```

potential families would be:

```
{1, 4, 5, 6}, {1, 4, 5, 7}, {1, 4, 6, 7}, {14, 25, 6, 6, 7}, ...
```

I want to find every family subset of the set. I don't really know how to proceed because of this age interval, which is specific for each pair of individuals. I don't really know how to form subsets from those.

In a next step I would choose the family with the most members. Thank you in advance

Comment: If you need to find a family with most members, you don't need to enumerate all families, that would be a waste of time.

Comment: I can't find a solution for either of these problems.

Comment: You've shown no effort to solve this on your own, even the simpler case of finding the largest family.  I'm not even sure you understand the problem, as your desired output confuses id's with ages.  This suggests that you need some time with a local tutor on problem analysis, rather than Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thank you for your constructive input. That's obviously a typo.

Comment: Your comment to the answer below includes a check "If the oldest person is too old", when apparently talking about choosing parents.  Is there an upper limit for parents -- or did you switch context to finding children?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Algorithm for finding the family with the most members

1. Sort ages
2. Take the 2 highest ages (called: P1, P2)
3. find the index of the highest age called `eldestChildAge` in the sorted ages where `age <= Min(P1, P2) - 15`
4. Now consider all the elements of the sorted ages which are less than `eldestChildAge` into this family (including `eldestChildAge` at most 9)

Hope this would help you understand.

Comment: That's a good approach. I will base my algorithm on this. However there are some problems: A family can be made of either one or two adults. So I would have to make two iterations of this algorithm. Besides, I would have to check if the oldest person is indeed an adult, so if the oldest adult is too young, I can stop. If the oldest person is too old, I will have to search for the second oldest and so on. Of course that's no big deal but it kind of bugs me to have these constraints here and there. Thank you very much.